# div not showing after setting display='block';

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

It works for a div that is not already hidden, but I start off with display set to none.

html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <button class ="col-md-6" ng-click="showAssessments()">Product Groups</button>
        <button class="col-md-6" ng-click="showSkills()">Skills</button>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-include src="detailsTemplate"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="skillsTemplate" style="display:none"></ng-include>
</div>
```

html of detailsTemplate (these are partial views)

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="assessmentForm"  id="assessmentForm">
    <!-- TODO: don't use table for layout -->
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" assessment-input-tabber>
      //......
    </table>
</form>
```

html of skillsTemplate

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" id="skillsTable">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" assessment-input-tabber>
       ......
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is my controller.js functions

```
       $scope.showSkills = function(){
            document.getElementById('assessmentForm').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('skillsTable').style.display = "block";
        };

        $scope.showAssessments = function(){
            document.getElementById('skillsTable').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('assessmentForm').style.display = "block";
        };
```

if I don't set display to none in ng-include src="skillsTemplate"... it works fine, except the first time it appears underneath my assessmentForm and doesn't go away until I click one of the buttons.

How do I get it to hide the skillsTable the first time, and then display upon the click?

Comment: what aabout using ng-show/ng-hide

Comment: I'm not very up on JS, but i cant help but notice you have single quotes on the first 'none' and double quotes on the second 'none' would that be affecting it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gk2eoym5/ continue with working code please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the `style="display:none"` on the `ng-include`, try using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` as @PetrAveryanov suggested:

HTML:

```
<ng-include src="detailsTemplate"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="skillsTemplate"></ng-include>
```

detailsTemplate:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="assessmentForm"  id="assessmentForm" ng-show="assessmentForm">
...
```

skillsTemplate:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" id="skillsTable" ng-show="skillsTable">
...
```

Then, in your controller, use:

```
    $scope.assessmentForm = true;
    $scope.skillsTable = false;
    $scope.showSkills = function(){
        $scope.assessmentForm = false;
        $scope.skillsTable = true;
    };
    $scope.showAssessments = function(){
        $scope.assessmentForm = true;
        $scope.skillsTable = false;
    };
```